# solr bin/post - specify a document ID

Tags: solr

I am quite new to solr as such, and have set up everything as per the example, and it all works fine. However, I have one nagging issue, for which I do not seem to find a solution for.

So, normally, I do the following using the `SimplePostTool` and it works like a charm:

```
bin/post -c mycorename /path/to/dir/document.pdf
```

and solr indexes this and assigns it an ID.

However, I have my own IDs, and I would like to specify the ID when I post .. something like so?:

```
bin/post -c mycorename /path/to/dir/document.pdf id=555
```

but the above  does not work - and I am struggling to find any docs which specify how to do this.

Any guidance on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bin/post -h` to see additional information, including `-params` option.

Then, you need to actually figure out the parameter name. Usually, it is something like `literal.id=555` as, for example, in [the ExtractingRequestHandler documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Examples).

Comment: That was spot on: I was missing `literal.` in my `post` command. Thanks so much - accepted your answer.